# FFT Convolution - 3x3 kernel

Tags: c#, image-processing, filter, fft, convolution

I have written some routines to sharpen a Grayscale image using a 3x3 kernel,

```
-1 -1 -1 
-1  9 -1 
-1 -1 -1
```

**The following code is working well in case of non-FFT (spatial-domain) convolution, but, not working in FFT-based (frequency-domain) convolution.**

The output image seems to be blurred.

I have several problems:

**(1)** This routine is not being able to generate desired result. It also freezes the application.

```
    public static Bitmap ApplyWithPadding(Bitmap image, Bitmap mask)
    {
        if(image.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
        {
            Bitmap imageClone = (Bitmap)image.Clone();
            Bitmap maskClone = (Bitmap)mask.Clone();

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Complex[,] cPaddedLena = ImageDataConverter.ToComplex(imageClone);
            Complex[,] cPaddedMask = ImageDataConverter.ToComplex(maskClone);

            Complex[,] cConvolved = Convolution.Convolve(cPaddedLena, cPaddedMask);

            return ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap(cConvolved);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("not a grascale");
        }
    }
```

**(2)** This routine gives good result. But, as slow as hell.

```
    public static Bitmap Apply(Bitmap sourceBitmap)
    {
        Sharpen filter = new Sharpen();

        BitmapData sourceData = sourceBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                 sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height),
                                 ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        byte[] pixelBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];
        byte[] resultBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];

        Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, pixelBuffer, 0, pixelBuffer.Length);

        sourceBitmap.UnlockBits(sourceData);

        double blue = 0.0;
        double green = 0.0;
        double red = 0.0;

        int filterWidth = filter.FilterMatrix.GetLength(1);
        int filterHeight = filter.FilterMatrix.GetLength(0);

        int filterOffset = (filterWidth - 1) / 2;
        int calcOffset = 0;

        int byteOffset = 0;

        for (int offsetY = filterOffset; offsetY < sourceBitmap.Height - filterOffset; offsetY++)
        {
            for (int offsetX = filterOffset; offsetX <
                sourceBitmap.Width - filterOffset; offsetX++)
            {
                blue = 0;
                green = 0;
                red = 0;

                byteOffset = offsetY *
                             sourceData.Stride +
                             offsetX * 4;

                for (int filterY = -filterOffset;
                    filterY <= filterOffset; filterY++)
                {
                    for (int filterX = -filterOffset;
                        filterX <= filterOffset; filterX++)
                    {

                        calcOffset = byteOffset +
                                     (filterX * 4) +
                                     (filterY * sourceData.Stride);

                        blue += (double)(pixelBuffer[calcOffset]) *
                                filter.FilterMatrix[filterY + filterOffset,
                                                    filterX + filterOffset];

                        green += (double)(pixelBuffer[calcOffset + 1]) *
                                 filter.FilterMatrix[filterY + filterOffset,
                                                    filterX + filterOffset];

                        red += (double)(pixelBuffer[calcOffset + 2]) *
                               filter.FilterMatrix[filterY + filterOffset,
                                                  filterX + filterOffset];
                    }
                }

                blue = filter.Factor * blue + filter.Bias;
                green = filter.Factor * green + filter.Bias;
                red = filter.Factor * red + filter.Bias;

                if (blue > 255)
                { blue = 255; }
                else if (blue < 0)
                { blue = 0; }

                if (green > 255)
                { green = 255; }
                else if (green < 0)
                { green = 0; }

                if (red > 255)
                { red = 255; }
                else if (red < 0)
                { red = 0; }

                resultBuffer[byteOffset] = (byte)(blue);
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 1] = (byte)(green);
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 2] = (byte)(red);
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 3] = 255;
            }
        }

        Bitmap resultBitmap = new Bitmap(sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height);

        BitmapData resultData = resultBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                 resultBitmap.Width, resultBitmap.Height),
                                 ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Marshal.Copy(resultBuffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, resultBuffer.Length);
        resultBitmap.UnlockBits(resultData);

        return resultBitmap;
    }
```

**(3)** The following is my GUI code. `SharpenFilter.ApplyWithPadding()` works properly if I use an image as a mask. But, doesn't work if I use a, say, `3`x`3` kernel.

```
    string path = @"E:\lena.png";
    string path2 = @"E:\mask.png";

    Bitmap _inputImage;
    Bitmap _maskImage;

    private void LoadImages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _inputImage = Grayscale.ToGrayscale(Bitmap.FromFile(path) as Bitmap);

        /*
        _maskImage = Grayscale.ToGrayscale(Bitmap.FromFile(path2) as Bitmap);
        */

        SharpenFilter filter = new SharpenFilter();
        double[,] mask = new double[,]  { { -1, -1, -1, }, 
                                        { -1,  9, -1, }, 
                                        { -1, -1, -1, }, };
        _maskImage = ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap(mask);

        inputImagePictureBox.Image = _inputImage;
        maskPictureBox.Image = _maskImage;
    }

    Bitmap _paddedImage;
    Bitmap _paddedMask;
    private void padButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap lena = Grayscale.ToGrayscale(_inputImage);
        Bitmap mask = Grayscale.ToGrayscale(_maskImage);

        ////Not working...
        //int maxWidth = (int)Math.Max(lena.Width, mask.Width);
        //int maxHeight = (int)Math.Max(lena.Height, mask.Height);

        ////This is working correctly in case if I use a png image as a mask.
        int maxWidth = (int)Tools.ToNextPow2(Convert.ToUInt32(lena.Width + mask.Width));
        int maxHeight = (int)Tools.ToNextPow2(Convert.ToUInt32(lena.Height + mask.Height));

        _paddedImage = ImagePadder.Pad(lena, maxWidth, maxHeight);
        _paddedMask = ImagePadder.Pad(mask, maxWidth, maxHeight);

        paddedImagePictureBox.Image = _paddedImage;
        paddedMaskPictureBox.Image = _paddedMask;
    }

    private void filterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Not working properly.
        // Freezes the application. 
        Bitmap sharp = SharpenFilter.ApplyWithPadding(_paddedImage, _paddedMask);

        ////Works well. But, very slow.
        //Bitmap sharp = SharpenFilter.Apply(_paddedImage);

        filteredPictureBox.Image = sharp as Bitmap;
    }
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Source Code :**

[image]

- You can download the entire solution from [here in this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxVqTx5Vp2gjUVduMy1YUWk3WkU/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Hi can you specified what `Convolution.Convolve(x,y)` does ?  In any case Convolution in fourrier space is a multiplication. So if you complexly multiplite term by term the fourrier transform of  cPaddedLena and cPaddedMask ( they should be padded to have the same dimension in fourrier space ) and take the invert fourrier transform the operation will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue appears to be with the interpretation of the kernel as an image consisting of unsigned byte values. As a result the `-1` values are converted to `255` effectively computing a convolution with the kernel

```
255 255 255
255  9  255
255 255 255
```

This can be immediately observed from white area in the "Convolution Kernel" image. The resulting kernel is thus that of a low-pass filter, producing a corresponding blurring effect.

**Probably the best way to handle this would be to read the kernel as a matrix of signed values instead of as an image.**

If you still prefer to handle the kernel as an image, you would need to convert the image back to signed values. The simplest way I can think of achieving this result would be to create a modified version of `ImageDataConverter.ToInteger(Bitmap)` where you map the bytes to signed values:

```
public static Complex[,] Unwrap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
  int Width = bitmap.Width;
  int Height = bitmap.Height;

  Complex[,] array2D = new Complex[bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height];
  ...

        else// If there is only one channel:
        {
          iii = (int)(*address);
          if (iii >= 128)
          {
            iii -= 256;
          }
        }
        Complex tempComp = new Complex((double)iii, 0.0);
        array2D[x, y] = tempComp;
```

You would then be able to convert your image in `SharpenFilter.ApplyWithPadding` with:

```
Complex[,] cPaddedMask =  ImageDataConverter.Unwrap(maskClone);
```

This should then give you the following result:

[image: Dynamic scaling lena]

While this improves on the sharpness of the image, you should immediately notice that the image is much darker than the original. This is due to the `Convolution.Rescale` function which dynamically rescales the image according to it's minimum and maximum value. This can be convenient to show the image with maximum dynamic range, but could result in a different overall scaling than a standard convolution. To achieve this standard scaling (based on the scaling of your FFT implementation), you could use the following implementation:

```
    //Rescale values between 0 and 255.
    private static void Rescale(Complex[,] convolve)
    {
        int imageWidth = convolve.GetLength(0);
        int imageHeight = convolve.GetLength(1);

        double scale = imageWidth * imageHeight;

        for (int j = 0; j < imageHeight; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
            {
                double re = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(convolve[i, j].Real * scale, 255.0));
                double im = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(convolve[i, j].Imaginary * scale, 255.0));
                convolve[i, j] = new Complex(re, im);
            }
        }
    }
```

This should then give you an image with a more appropriate brightness level:

[image: Standard scaling]

Finally, for a filtering operation one would typically expect the result to match the original image size (unlike a convolution which includes the tails). Cropping the result in `SharpenFilter.ApplyWithPadding` with:

```
...
// -3 terms are due to kernel size
// +5 vertical offset term is due to vertical reflection & offset in SetPixel
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((cPaddedLena.GetLength(0) / 2 - 3) / 2,
                               (cPaddedLena.GetLength(1) / 2 - 3) / 2 + 5, 
                               cPaddedLena.GetLength(0) / 2,
                               cPaddedLena.GetLength(1) / 2);
return ImageDataConverter.ToBitmap(cConvolved).Clone(rect, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

should give you:

[image: sharpened image]

For easier visual comparison, here is the original image again:

[image: original image]